# Eclipse RCP & tycho - The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

**Situation:** 
I have an Eclipse RCP Application, which I am trying to build with tycho plugin for Eclipse. 
When I am executing my Eclipse Application inside of the IDe - the Application is executed normally. 
When using tycho to build the Application - the following error is thrown:

```
The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

**What I did :** 
In other cases where a "missing requirenments" exception was thrown, which I found 
- [a missing transitive plugin-dependency was the reason](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/TYCHO-400).

In my case an SWT widget "Button" is missing, so I am trying to import swt.
SWT is platform dependant so I am importing swt inside of the **product**, as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ).

Anyway, during compilation the error occurs again.

**Question:**  
Do someone have any Idea, how to solve this Problem?

Comment: Good question, don't have an answer but somewhere in your tycho configuration or files its not adding the right plugins, how to resolve that I'm not sure.

Comment: You might want to copy in the answer from the tycho-users mailing list :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the mailing list (Thnx Jeff MAURY!) - it seems to be a bug of tycho.
[Here](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/8163/) is a patch available.

For those, who do not know GIT yet, like me:

- When checking out the patch on windows use TortoiseGit or MSYGit clients, not the EGit Client - it wont recognize the repository.
- Additionally use the **https** repository, not the git repository - git didn't work for me
- And the checkot syntax is `git clone https://git.eclipse.org/r/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git` - https://git.eclipse.org/r/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git is the repository URL here