# Tycho can't resolve indirectly referenced SWT dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swt, tycho

*The problem is probably the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255774/eclipse-rcp-tycho-the-type-org-eclipse-swt-widgets-button-cannot-be-resolved), but the solution offered there has become inapplicable in the last 8 years.*

---

I have an Eclipse RCP project which is in the process of being transformed to use Tycho (version 2.3.0) instead. **The project can be run with Eclipse** 2019-06 and the custom target platform built for this project.

Then I have set up Tycho with the same target platform (a separate Maven module referencing the same *.target file used by Eclipse).

But then when I run Maven (version 3.6.3) with the usual "clean install" goals, I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:2.3.0:compile (default-compile) on project my.project.module: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] C:\path\to\a\source\file\in\a\module.java: 
[ERROR]     /*
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR] The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

The target platform specifies the same environment (*win32.win32.x86_64*) for both Eclipse and Tycho, and both SWT .jar files (*org.eclipse.swt_3.111.0.v20190605-1801.jar* and *org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.111.0.v20190605-1801.jar*) are in one of the directories making up the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

After adding

`jars.extra.classpath = platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64`

to the `build.properties` file (as recommended [here](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/tycho-user/msg02151.html)) the problem is gone.

Comment: **Don't do this.** That's a hack for the wrong assumption Tycho can't resolve indirectly referenced SWT dependencies. It's an issue on your side. See e.g. [this working example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) without this hack.

Comment: @howlger I'm facing the same issue as the OP and the github repo you linked to references org.eclipse.swt the same way that I do. Why do you say that's a hack? How can one avoid that hack? I'm looking to pinpoint the exact flaw that causes the error message about an indirect reference. Thanks.

Comment: @AbVog The linked working example shows how to do it. Something is wrong in your plugin's `MANIFEST.MF` or your target platform. There is no need to misuse `jars.extra.classpath` for that.