# After changing location in Target file, Tycho can not resolve indirectly referenced dependency

Tags: java, maven, swt, eclipse-rcp, tycho

*This might be a duplication of [Tycho can't resolve indirectly referenced SWT dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104594/tycho-cant-resolve-indirectly-referenced-swt-dependencies), but the given answer does not work for me, so I am not sure.*

---

My goal is to update my Target Platform definition file version-by-version from `Eclipse Luna` to the most recent Eclipse version, which still supports Java 8.
But I am stuck in the step from Eclipse `2018-09` to `2018-12`.

Based on Eclipse `2018-09` I can start my application from Eclipse and I can build it with Tycho 1.7.0.
(Tycho 1.7.0 is also the most current version, which still supports Java 8.)

The working target file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde?>
<!-- generated with https://github.com/eclipse-cbi/targetplatform-dsl -->
<target name="My Target" sequenceNumber="1622530056">
  <locations>
    <location includeMode="planner" includeAllPlatforms="false" includeSource="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.15.0.v20180904-1442"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.9.0.I20180906-0745"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.15.0.v20180906-0745"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat" version="4.7.200.v20180821-1411"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.services" version="4.8.100.v20180821-1411"/>
      <repository id="eclipse-luna" location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-09"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
</target>
```

Based on Eclipse `2018-12` I can start my application from Eclipse but I can not build it with Tycho 1.7.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde?>
<!-- generated with https://github.com/eclipse-cbi/targetplatform-dsl -->
<target name="My Target" sequenceNumber="1622530674">
  <locations>
    <location includeMode="planner" includeAllPlatforms="false" includeSource="true" includeConfigurePhase="false" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.16.0.v20181130-2106"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.10.0.I20181206-0815"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.16.0.v20181206-1038"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat" version="4.7.300.v20181015-0338"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.services" version="4.8.200.v20181022-1512"/>
      <repository id="eclipse-luna" location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
</target>
```

The error I get is the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.my_plugin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] C:\path\to\my_project\my_plugin\SomeClass.java: 
[ERROR]     package some.package;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR] The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

---

#### Things I already tried

- I tried to build the project with Tycho 2.3.0 (and Java 11) but I get the indirectly referenced classes error.
- I tried adding `jars.extra.classpath = platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` as proposed by [Tycho can't resolve indirectly referenced SWT dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104594/tycho-cant-resolve-indirectly-referenced-swt-dependencies).
  But then I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.my_plugin 5.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.my_plugin 5.0.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

- According to the [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpde_feature_generating_build.htm&cp%3D4_3_1_1) it seems to be `platform:/plugins` and not `platform:/plugin`.
  But that again leads to to the indirectly referenced classes error.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-03 supports Java 8 and upcoming releases will support Java 8, but require Java 11 or higher to run. Do not use `jars.extra.classpath` here (and do not believe everything you read on Stack Overflow). Use latest Eclipse and Tycho and have a look at https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example instead.

Comment: Possibly try `includeAllPlatforms="true"` (rather than `false`) in the target file

Comment: `includeAllPlatforms` seems to go in the right direction. If I only build the application for win32-x86_64, then Tycho is successful. I have not tried `includeAllPlatforms="true"` yet, because that means that I have to switch from  `planner` to `slicer`.
This might work, but in the `tycho-example` the `includeAllPlatforms="false"` and `planner` combination is also used, so I might still miss something else.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to start with the working Tycho example and then change it step by step to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the problem was very mundane.
I was still building my project for Windows 32-bit.

If I remove

```
<environment>
  <os>win32</os>
  <ws>win32</ws>
  <arch>x86</arch>
</environment>
```

from my `target-platform-configuration` the project can be build again.

---

I tried to replicate the error with the `tycho-example` by Vogella and was successful.

If I put the `win32_x86` environment as the *first* environment I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:2.3.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[1] 
[ERROR]     package com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui.handlers;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR] The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[20] 
[ERROR]     import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
[ERROR]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell cannot be resolved
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[27] 
[ERROR]     public void execute(final IProvisioningAgent agent, final Shell shell, final UISynchronize sync,
[ERROR]                                                               ^^^^^
[ERROR] Shell cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[38] 
[ERROR]     private IStatus checkForUpdates(final IProvisioningAgent agent, final Shell shell, final UISynchronize sync,
[ERROR]                                                                           ^^^^^
[ERROR] Shell cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[70] 
[ERROR]     private void configureProvisioningJob(ProvisioningJob provisioningJob, final Shell shell, final UISynchronize sync,
[ERROR]                                                                                  ^^^^^
[ERROR] Shell cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\gillesB\git\gilles\tycho-example\bundles\com.vogella.tycho.p2.ui\src\com\vogella\tycho\p2\ui\handlers\UpdateHandler.java:[98] 
[ERROR]     private void showMessage(final Shell parent, final UISynchronize sync) {
[ERROR]                                    ^^^^^
[ERROR] Shell cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] 6 problems (6 errors)
```

So the the indirectly referenced classes error also appears.
I built the `tycho-example` with Windows 10 (64-bit) and Java Corretto 11 (64-bit).

If I put the `win32_x86` environment as the *last* environment I get another clearer error message, that a 32-bit dependency can not be found.

Comment: I am still wondering why this is not noted in the [upgrade guide](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fporting%2F4.10%2Fincompatibilities.html).
But perhaps it is a Tycho problem and I looked in the wrong place?